# RadGrid Clear Filters

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik RadGrid with AutoGenerateColumns-AtRuntime=true.i need to clear the filters in the radgrid on a button click.i have the following code which is not working

```
  foreach (GridColumn column in  gridSearchL3.MasterTableView.OwnerGrid.Columns)
        {
            column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter;
            column.CurrentFilterValue = string.Empty;
        }
          gridSearchL3.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below link.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-clear-filters.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be:

```
foreach (GridColumn column in gridSearchL3.MasterTableView.Columns)
{
   column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter;
   column.CurrentFilterValue = String.Empty;
}
gridSearchL3.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = String.Empty;
```

I use this code on a button press to clear filters on my web order portal and it seems to work fine. I'd guess that your for each statement is slightly different.